# Getting stack data from Error Objects in React Native - Expo - CRNA

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling, expo, create-react-native-app

I would like to be able to get the stack data (fileName and lineNumber) from an Error object in React Native.
If I run something like this:

```
const err = new Error('Message');
console.log(err);
```

I get some helpful output in my console like this:

```
Message
* App.js:21:16 in componentDidMount
- node_modules\react-proxy\modules\createPrototypeProxy.js:61:45 in proxiedComponentDidMount
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:10627:12 in commitLifeCycles
- ... 23 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I would like to be able to send that stack data off elsewhere for logging and fixing, but I can't figure out how to access the data which shows the filename and the line where the error was generated.
How can I get that information?
As per the documentation [Error - JavaScript   MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), if I try:

```
console.log(err.fileName)
```

or:

```
console.log(err.lineNumber)
```

I just get:

```
undefined
```

Which is confirmed by:

```
console.log(Object.keys(err));
```

resulting in:

```
Array []
```

Although, mysteriously:

```
console.log(err.message);
```

still returns:

```
Message
```

Related - if I enter:

```
console.log(err.toString())
```

I get:

```
Error: Message
```

Similarly, if I enter:

```
console.log('Comment', err);
```

I get as output:

```
Comment [Error: Message]
```

So while I can see the stack data is there, I don't seem to be able to access it or pass it somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

check out https://github.com/marchingband/expo-error-log.
You'll need to register your own Error Handler callback.
You can use an ErrorBoundary, or capture the errors in a number of other ways, some of which will capture all the JS errors, some of which will not.